"I", "I'd" and "I had" questions
I wanted to know if the sentence "I wish I understood." is correct. I couldn't find any similar uses online, I always find uses with anothers words or "I'd" or "I had" instead. Is it still right if I use only "I"?
The use would be a song name.

Where did you look for similar uses? There's already a song with that very name.

This question is similar to: Wish + tense agreement + subordinate clause. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@EdwinAshworth Thanks. Our tagging system misled me.

As usual, both are correct but both mean different things. One is a wish for the future, the other a wish for the past.

I wish I understood what he is saying.

I wish I had understood what he was saying.


The first expresses a wish that the present situation were otherwise. It's about a present condition that could yet be changed in the future. It’s a wish for the future.
The second expresses a wish that a past situation had been otherwise. It's about a past condition which already came to pass and so can no longer be changed. It's a wish for the past.

Thank you so much!! This really cleared all my doubts
